# Corona SDK - any way to integrate iAds?

Tags: api, iad, coronasdk

I don't see any mention of it in the API. Wondering if it's possible to incorporate ads in any way into a Corona game.

Answer (score 2):

Your title asks if there's any way to integrate iAds in Corona SDK -- the answer to that is no, at this time. But I believe Ansca Mobile is working on that so I expect to see it sooner or later.

As jhocking points out, there are ways to get Admobs to work in Corona SDL apps that work fairly well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to integrate third party SDK's into a Lua based framework, check out the Moai game development SDK at http://getmoai.com

Moai is open source, so you can integrate anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

The fill rates on iAds are far below expectation so they aren't a huge loss. AdMob can be used via a trick involving web views:

http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/tag/corona/

Answer (score 0):

Now Carona allows you to implement ads and is not so hard.

Here is an example:

[corona-admob-example](https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-ads-admob)